# Upgrade from Angular 8 to v12 causing "Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

Tags: angular

I have been working on upgrading an angular app from v8 to v12. I have completed all the upgrade steps by going through each version. That all went pretty well. However, I am trying to run the project "ng serve" and I am getting a cryptic error compilation error message that I have not been able to figure out.

Here is the error that ng serve is spitting out. I get the same error for ng build as well.

---

```
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at NodeObject.getText (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:152697:31)
    at getRequiredModulePath (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/host/umd_host.js:519:99)
    at Object.getImportsOfUmdModule (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/host/umd_host.js:510:23)
    at UmdDependencyHost.extractImports (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/umd_dependency_host.js:43:54)
    at UmdDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.recursivelyCollectDependencies (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_host.js:85:32)
    at UmdDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.collectDependencies (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_host.js:38:22)
    at DependencyResolver.getEntryPointWithDependencies (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_resolver.js:75:22)
    at EntryPointCollector.walkDirectoryForPackages (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/entry_point_collector.js:47:52)
    at EntryPointCollector.walkDirectoryForPackages (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/entry_point_collector.js:75:103)
    at /Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/program_based_entry_point_finder.js:124:100
/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:139
            throw new Error(errorMessage + `NGCC failed${errorMessage ? ', see above' : ''}.`);
            ^

Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:139:19)
    at /Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:129:27
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), :32:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1043:30)
    at /Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1088:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :22:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (/Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1083:28)
    at /Users/ericdeveloper/Development/ClientApps/TBVApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:200:19
```

---

I found another post that had a similar error. It said there was an issue with angular v12.2.12. I tried downgrading to v12.2.4 but it didn't help.

Here is my package.json contents...

```
{
  "name": "fury",
  "version": "7.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key ../../SSL/localhostdev.key --ssl-cert ../../SSL/localhostdev.crt --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck",
    "build": "node --trace-warnings ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "buildtest": "node --trace-warnings & export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 & ng build  --extract-css=false --configuration test --aot --outputHashing=all",
    "buildprod": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 &  ng build  --extract-css=false --prod --aot --outputHashing=all",
    "memory": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192",
    "update:packages": "node wipe-dependencies.js && rm -rf node_modules && npm update --save-dev && npm update --save"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/youtube-player": "~12.2.4",
    "@cloudinary/angular": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "@cloudinary/angular-5.x": "^1.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@opentok/client": "^2.21.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.20.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.8",
    "@types/twilio-video": "^2.11.0",
    "@videojs/http-streaming": "^2.11.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.28",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^12.1.0",
    "chart.js": "~3.6.0",
    "chart.piecelabel.js": "~0.15.0",
    "cloudinary-core": "^2.12.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "~2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "~11.3.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "~2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^12.0.1",
    "ngx-audio-player": "^11.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap-modal": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^12.0.3",
    "ngx-countdown": "^12.0.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-quill": "~14.3.0",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-toasta": "^2.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "~8.0.1",
    "npm": "^8.1.2",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "reinstall": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "safe-pipe": "^1.0.3",
    "screenfull": "~5.1.0",
    "signalr": "^2.4.2",
    "simplebar": "~5.3.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "store-js": "^2.0.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "twilio-video": "^2.18.1",
    "video.js": "^7.15.4",
    "videojs-overlay": "^2.1.5",
    "videojs-resume": "^0.3.2",
    "videojs-youtube": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "~12.2.4",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.5",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.6",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-plugin-clean-css": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.4.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I have tried reinstalling all the node_modules, etc. Any ideas on how to get at this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this error by basically starting with a barebones package.json and starting adding all the dependencies in one by one. Oddly enough, I have them all added and I never did find the offending component.

My guess is that there must have been an issue with a peer dependency. By going step by step, it seemed to circumvent that issue. It was a little painful to go through, but it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue after an upgrade.

What finally fixed it for me was deleting package-lock.json. I also deleted node_modules, but I think the actual fix was blowing away package-lock.json and letting npm recreate it.

As a side note, I had upgraded npm to 8.1, and ended up downgrading it back to 7.24. Not sure if this was a factor as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just gave that a try but no luck :(.  I am not too familiar with the IVY compiler, but I feel that the issue might be related to that. Thanks for the tip. I just gave that a try but no luck :(.  I am not too familiar with the IVY compiler, but I feel that the issue might be related to that.

My app was based off a UI template that I customized. I downloaded the upgraded version of the template for Angular 12. It has this postinstall script that generates the same error when I run it. 

ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points

Comment: I guess there might be an issue with one of the libraries I am using and maybe not being compatible with angular 12. I am having a hard time finding the offending library.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by removing ng-bootstrap from the packages. It is included by another package already it seems.

My package.json content:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.6",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "ngx-summernote": "^0.8.7",
    "summernote": "^0.8.20",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^12.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.1.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
}
```